# Creating environment from yml file avoids pip installable packages?

Tags: environment-variables, conda

I created a a .yml file from a well stable conda env.

The .yml file states the following at the end which basically points to other packages that cannot be obtained from conda channels:

```
  - pip:
    - easygui==0.98.1
    - nptdms==0.12.0
```

When creating a new env using this .yml file, it completely avoided installing these two packages. Is that something the user has to do manually? If yes, doesn't that defeat the purpose of creating-sharing .yml env file?